# setting the length of an array's string element to a variable in a for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code. and for some reason i get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. I can't seem to figure out why.

```js
function findShort(s) {

  var c = s.split(' ');
  var l = c[0].length;
  var wordlength;

  for (var i = 1; c.length; i++) {
    console.log(c[i].length);

    wordlength = c[i].length;
    if (l < wordlength) {
      l = wordlength;

    }
  }
  return l;

}

console.log(findShort("hello dog cat 12 asdsad wuidhuiwqhd"));
```

the error is with the line `wordlength = c[i].length;`

When i console.log it, it shows the length of each string in the array. However, when i try to store that length it says it's undefined.

Comment: You have an infinite loop, since `c.length` doesn't change during the loop. So you keep going past the end of the array.

Comment: doh! i can't believe i didn't notice that. thank you so much

Comment: `console.log(Math.min.apply(null, 'the quick brown fox jumped'.split(' ').map(w=>w.length))); // outputs "3"`

Comment: whoa. way better solution. I will have to learn more about arrow functions and mapping. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change this line

```
for ( var i = 1; c.length; i++ ) {
```

to

```
for ( var i = 1; i<c.length; i++ ) {
```

The second componenet of a `for` loop is a boolean condition that is checked for every round of the loop to determine if the loop should continue or not. By putting `c.length`, you are giving a constant value which will make the loop to either never run (if `c.length` is 0), or to run forever (if `c.length` not 0).

You should also be careful with the following line:

```
var l = c[0].length;
```

It might cause a problem too as it is not guaranteed that `c` will have at least one element.

Comment: I am a moron. Didn't notice that and i poured over the code 100 times. thank you very much